# trying to get an output from a file using the user input value then print the value in python

Tags: python, file-handling

I'm trying to learn python and I wrote this script, that not shows me the right output.. What am i missing?

I have a text file like this:

> test
>
> test1
>
> test2
>
> test3
>
> test4
>
> #test5
>
> test6
>
> #test7
>
> #test8

**TASK 1:**

1. *open file*: i got this part
2. *do not print or ignore any line that starts with *"#"*: i think i got this part (fread2)

Here is my code:

```
fopen=open('file1.txt',mode='r+')
fread=fopen.read()
fread2="\n".join([line.strip() for line in fread.splitlines() if not line.startswith('#')])

print(fread2)

fopen.close()
```

Output:

> test
>
> test1
>
> test2
>
> test3
>
> test4
>
> test6

*Note*: test5, 7 and 8 did not print. Success!

**TASK 2:**

1. *ask user to input a text*: completed
2. *from fread2 output - use the user "input" value and if value exit, then print that line only*: failed!!

See the following code:

```
fopen=open('file1.txt',mode='r+')
fread=fopen.read()
fread2="\n".join([line.strip() for line in fread.splitlines() if not line.startswith('#')])
text=input("Enter text: ")
for x in fread2:
    if text == "":
        continue
    if text in x:
        print(x)
fopen.close()
```

Output

> Enter text: test

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of "*from fread2 output - use the user "input" value and if value exit, then print that line only*"? Do you want to check if the input equals one line of the text file?

Comment: hi - sorry im new to python. thats correct! im trying to use the "fread2" output to find the user input. if the user input exist in fread2, then print the line. thanks!

Comment: the value in text will be `test` but the value in x will include `\n` so it will never be the same. Also fread2 will be a concatenated string. If you print fread2 you will see the difference.

Comment: hi joe - sorry there was a typo in if test == "":, that's meant to be "text" NOT "test"

Comment: the for loop will pull each character. You are going to compare each char to what's in the input string. That will never give you the desired result. Instead you may want to read the line. fread2 is a string so for loop will pick each char for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `fread2` variable is one big string containing all lines. When you iterate over a string, you iterate over its **characters**. So an example iteration of your loop is:

```py
if "test" in "e":
    print(x)
```

It's easy to see that this is not what you were going for.

To solve this, you can iterate through the lines by doing:

```
for x in fread2.split("\n"):
```

But, personally I think a more *elegant* solution would be to save the lines in a list to begin with, and only change the way you print it:

```py
with open('file1.txt',mode='r+') as fopen:
    fread = [line.strip() for line in fopen if not line.startswith('#')]

# first assignment
print(*fread, sep='\n')

#second assignment
text = input("Enter text: ")
for line in fread:
    if text == line:
        print(line)
```

Note that I used [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to open the file which is the idiomatic way of doing so.

Comment: "*So of course it's easy to see that the condition will never hold true.*". If the user wrote a single character (in this case "e"), the condition would be verified.  Yes, that's not what he wants, and the entire contents of the file would be printed instead of a single line... But it is not entirely correct to say that this condition will never be True.

Comment: @Calaf that's hard to argue with! You are definitely right. I will change the wording to be more accurate

Comment: @Tomerikoo - working and the output is correct. one problem though is when in put is "test" it prints, all line with "test" in it, however, if input is "test4" the output is fine.

Enter text: test
test
test1
test2
test3
test4
test6


Enter text: test4
test4

Comment: @Tomerikoo, in the above code, if you replace `if text in line:` with `if text == line`, you will get the result you are looking for

Comment: @sendoh your question was not clear about this part and so I followed your code. Of course checking using `in` is partial and will work if the text is **somewhere** in the string. If you want exact matches it should be `==` of course

Comment: @Temerikoo thank you! - also thank you to the other guys who help me on this problem very helpful. thank you guys for helping me on this. For now this is resolved. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your *fread2* is a single string, so when you call `for x in fread2` you are iterating on every single letter, not on every row of the file. You can see this by doing:

```
for x in fread2:
    print(x)
```

You have to save all the lines in a list or iterate on the file rows.

**EXAMPLE**

Try to follow this code:

```
fopen=open('file1.txt',mode='r+')
fread=fopen.read()

fread2=[]

for line in fread.splitlines():
    if not line.startswith('#'):
        fread2.append(line) #this is important! 
                            #If you write "+=" you'll iterate on every single letter

text=input("Enter text: ")
for x in fread2:
    if text in x:
        print("I've found "+x)
fopen.close()
```

If the user write "2", your output will be:

[image: output example]

---

**UPDATE**

As requested in the comments, If you want to check if the user input equals a file line you have to replace

```
if text in x:
```

with

```
if text==x:
```

So, if the user write *"text"*, the lines *"text2", "text3"* etc. will be not printed!

Here is an output example:

[image: output 2 example]

Comment: @sendoh Read the "Update" part: it should now work as you want.